# What is the best Workflow tool

Tags: delphi, winapi, workflow

Preferable free, open source, vcl. For Delphi 2007 or above and win32.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [Workflow Studio](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/workflow.asp)? You say you prefer free and open source, but is it a requirement? If not, Workflow Studio isn't very expensive (249 EUR for single developer license, 795 EUR for site license with source code).

Comment: As much as possible I use open source, software tends to be more flexible and updated. Not all.
Be if I cannot find it free, of course will pay. The project must go one…

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you on that one. 800 EUR (about $1600 US) is a lot to get the source code. :/

Comment: @Fabricio, my answer was posted a year and a half ago.